# hibernate: create table with names in lowercase

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, orm

Hibernate: I want to have hibernate automatically generate my tables with names in lowercase.

For example, if my class is called com.myapp.domain.Customer, hibernate will generate a table named Customer. I want it to be called customer. I know I can use the @Table annotation to specify the table name per class. But I want it to happen "automagically".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isn'it it the job for [NamingStrategy](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/cfg/NamingStrategy.html)?

You would get the name of the entity managed (i.e. Customer) and should decide the table name used (`entityName.toLowerCase()` in your case).

One thing I am not sure is if the NamingStrategies are taken into account when generating tables (hbm2ddl).

Comment: You are right and there is an option to hbm2ddl to specify naming strategy. The particular implementation that you're looking for is `org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy`.