# Force lowercase table names in Play Framework

Tags: mysql, jpa, playframework

On this one project I develop on Windows and deploy on Linux, and use mysql as database.

Because of the filesystem nature, table names (and more, I suppose) are case insensitive on windows, and sensitive on *nix [[Ref]](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

Problem is, by default play/jpa uses the same name as the java model class for the table (so it is capitalized, eg. UserProfile). When I dump my windows mysql database it dumps lowercase table names.

Which means I can't import them in Linux because of the case sensitivity.

Is there a way to tell Play / JPA to always use lowercase names for the models?
Or must I set a `@Table(name="userprofile")` annotation on any single model?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a different naming strategy for hibernate. There is an improved NS available with hibernate

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/ImprovedNamingStrategy.html

you can simply add this line to application.conf

```
hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
```

Look also at [this](http://matthew.mceachen.us/blog/hibernate-naming-strategies-20.html) post and at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657119/hibernate-create-table-with-names-in-lowercase) SO question

Comment: thanks @mericano1; from a previously removed answer (why?!) and these tickets: [#616](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987-play-framework/tickets/616-make-it-possible-to-use-a-custom-namingstrategy-for-jpa-hibernate), [#769](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/769-give-programmatic-access-to-the-ejb3configuration-at-configuration-time) it looks like this will not work on Play 1.2.* and i'm currently on 1.2.4 (I'll move to 1.3 as soon as it's out). I'll test this myself in any case, but.. have you tried it yourself so that you can confirm it works as advertised?

Comment: I have used other `hibernate.ebj.*` properties and they do work fine. Specifically I'm using the ejb events. Look at this [audit log project](https://github.com/mericano1/play-auditlog), at the bottom there is a usage section, that's what I specifically have